# What is a convenient way to run long list of commands, and show a message if something goes wrong?

Tags: bash, shell

Most Linux guides consist of pages like
"you need to run `command_1`, then `command_2`, then `command_3`" etc. Since I don't want to waste my time running all of them manually, I'd rather create a script

```
command_1
command_2
command_3
```

and run it once. But, more often than not, some commands will fail, and I will have no idea, which commands have failed. Also, usually all the rest commands make no sense if something failed earlier. So a better script would be something like

```bsh
   (command_1 && echo OK command_1 || (echo FAILED command_1; false) )
&& (command_2 && echo OK command_2 || (echo FAILED command_2; false) )
&& (command_3 && echo OK command_3 || (echo FAILED command_3; false) )
&& echo DONE 
|| echo FAILED
```

But it requires to write too much boilerplate code, repeat each command 3 times, and there is too high chance, that I mistype some of the braces. Is there a more convenient way of doing what the last script does? In particular:

- run commands sequentially
- break if any command fails
- write, what command has failed, if any
- Allows normal interactions with commands: prints all output, and allows input from keyboard, if command asks anything.

## Answers summary (2 January 2020)

There are 2 types of solutions:

- Those, that allow to copy-paste commands from guide without modifications, but they don't print the failed command in the end. So, if failed command produced a very long output, you will have to scroll a lot of lines up, to see, what command has failed. (All top answers)
- Those, that print the failed command in the last line, but require you to modify commands after copy-pasting them, either by adding quotations (answer by John), or by adding `try` statements and splitting chained commands into separate ones (answer by Jasen).

You rock folks, but I'll leave this question opened for a while. Maybe someone knows a solution that satisfies both needs (print failed command on the last line & allow copy-pasting of commands without their modifications).

Answer (score 63):

One option would be to put the commands in a bash script, and start it with `set -e`.

This will cause the script to terminate early if any command exits with non-zero exit status.

See also this question on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19622198/828193

To print the error, you could use

```
trap 'do_something' ERR
```

Where `do_something` is a command you would create to show the error.

Here is an example of a script to see how it works:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
trap 'echo "******* FAILED *******" 1>&2' ERR

echo 'Command that succeeds'   # this command works
ls non_existent_file           # this should fail
echo 'Unreachable command'     # and this is never called
                               # due to set -e
```

And this is the output:

```
$ ./test.sh 
Command that succeeds
ls: cannot access 'non_existent_file': No such file or directory
******* FAILED *******
```

Also, as mentioned by **@jick**, keep in mind that the exit status of a pipeline is by default the exit status of the *final* command in it. This means that if a non-final command in the pipeline fails, that won't be caught by `set -e`. To fix this problem if you are concerned with it, you can use `set -o pipefail`

---

As suggested my **@glenn jackman** and **@Monty Harder**, using a function as the handler can make the script more readable, since it avoids nested quoting. Since we are using a function anyway now, I removed `set -e` entirely, and used `exit 1` in the handler, which could also make it more readable for some:

```
#!/bin/bash

error_handler() {
  echo "******* FAILED *******" 1>&2
  exit 1
}

trap error_handler ERR

echo 'Command that succeeds'   # this command works
ls non_existent_file           # this should fail
echo 'Unreachable command'     # and this is never called
                               # due to the exit in the handler
```

The output is identical as above, though the exit status of the script is different.

Comment: It can be clearer to make `do_something` a function: `trap do_something ERR; do_something() { echo "FAILED" >&2; }` -- that also makes it easier to do multiple things in the cleanup code.

Comment: Also `set -u` for variables

Comment: Definitely follow @glennjackman's suggestion to make it a function, but rather than naming it `do_something()` let's give it a more meaningful name like `trap ErrorHandler ERR;` and define `ErrorHandler()` with all of the steps to handle errors.  You _think_ you just want to echo FAILED to stderr.  But sooner or later you'll decide to add more to it.

Comment: Adding `set -x` to print each command before it is executed gives much better visibility into what step fatally failed, and what went on beforehand.

Comment: @mtraceur: That's very good for debugging, but otherwise the output can get pretty verbose. For the script above, it went from 3 lines to 9.

Comment: @user000001 You're absolutely right - now the important question is: is that *really* a problem? Sometimes it is, but a lot of the times, it actually isn't. We need to be discerning with our intuiton that it is bad. For example, at work we have a lot of deployment, build, and automation scripts which spew out thousands of lines due to `set -x`, always. But it's not actually a problem because we ignore them until something goes wrong, and when it does we love the visibility. On the other hand, for a *polished program* for which human parsing of output is the normal usecase, `set -x` is bad.

Comment: Can it be modified in such a way, that it prints the failed command on the last line? It's useful, for example, if commands are `compile abc` and `compile xyz`. If one of them fails, then you will only see a very long and obscure output, a line `******* FAILED *******`, and you will still have no idea, if abc have failed, or xyz. And if you're unlucky enough, then output of commands will be longer than the buffer of your terminal, so even `set -x` will not help you (unless you piped the output to a file foreseeing this scenario).

Comment: @Arqwer AFAIK The only easy way is to use `set -x`, as suggested in other answers/comments. That will cause all commands to be printed though, not only the one that failed.

Comment: `set -e` is magic.

Answer (score 20):

Want an unusual solution? If you have `make` installed then you could put the list of commands in a `Makefile` for `make` to execute. Added advantage: you don't have to check if any errors occured. `make` will automatically check the return value of each command. If it is non-zero, the recipe is terminated with an error. If you want to ignore errors with certain commands, chain them with `|| true`.

Sample Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all
.SILENT:

all:
    echo "Started list of commands."
    true
    echo "Executing a command which will fail, but I want to ignore failure."
    false || true
    echo "Executing a command which will definitely fail."
    false
    echo "This code will not be reached."
```

Note: Make (heh) sure to indent your commands like above, but with a tab.

Comment: +1 great out-of-the-box thinking/hack, repurposing `make` for another task. Portability is pretty good too (though an `sh` is almost always more readily available than a `make`).

Comment: what is the `.PHONY: all
.SILENT:` part for?

Comment: @törzsmókus [`.PHONY:`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) tells make that all of the following targets (in this case, the target `all`) are not real files. Otherwise, make will normally determine whether to "build" a target based partially on the modification timestamp or existence of the file with the matching name. [`.SILENT:`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Targets) just tells make to shut up and not print all the commands it's about to run and instead just run them.

Comment: @8bittree thx for the clarification and reference!

Answer (score 16):

I believe this only works for bash, but you can try:

```
set -o xtrace
set -o errexit
```

Or, if you want to be concise,

```
set -ex
```

This will do two things: `errexit` (-e) will abort the script when there is an error, and `xtrace` (-x) will print each command just before bash executes it, so in case of failure you know exactly what it was executing.

One downside is that it will clutter the output, but as long as you're OK with that this is a pretty good solution with minimal work.

- While we're at it, it's usually a good idea to also include `set -o pipefail`: otherwise, if you run `foo | bar`, failure of `foo` will be silently ignored.  (Warning: it subtly changes the "exit code" of a pipe statement, so use with caution if you're modifying someone else's script.  Also, sometimes you actually don't care about `foo`'s failure, so obviously you can't use `pipefail` in such a a case.)

Comment: `xtrace` and `errexit` are POSIX. `-e` and `-x` are even Bourne (where they come from). `pipefail` comes from ksh93 and is also supported by bash, mksh,  zsh, busybox and yash at least.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas It's worth noting that `set -o pipefail` won't work for dash, which is a fairly common `/bin/sh` nowadays. `-e` and `-x` do work in dash of course.

Comment: @marcelm, true, though it will likely be added there sooner or later since [`pipefail` will make it to the next version of the POSIX specification](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=789)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Oh cool, that's good to know!

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
$ for f in command_1 command_2 command_3 command_4
do
  $f
  rc=$?
  if [[ 0 != $rc ]]; then echo Failed command: ${f}; break; fi
done
```

This assumes the commands have no options, if they do you'll need to enclose each command/option set within quotes.

Comment: could get tricky if any commands set and use variables - probable shell injection.

Comment: This could get messy if any of the commands has multiple words (which is highly likely), especially if any of them is a compound / complex command, or contains quoted/escaped special characters.  @Jasen: Can you give an example of how this approach could be significantly worse than the strawman approach given in the question — simply listing the commands in a script file?  Are you worried about commands changing `f`?

Answer (score 3):

```
failed=0
try(){
(( failed )) && return
"$@" 
ec=$?
if (( ec ))
then
  failed=$ec
  echo "failed($failed): $*" >&2
fi
}

try something args
try other-thing more args

if (( failed )) 
then
  echo "something went wrong: see above." >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: The idea behind this script is sound, but I made some edits to fix some typos that were preventing it from working.

Comment: @Kevdog777 I have asked on meta about the edit you rejected, feel free to provide your feedback if you want: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5476/suggestion-should-be-comment-but-it-really-shouldnt

Comment: @Romeo Ninov: ^ same as above.

Comment: Look, if the commands are
`try ls -la ~ && ls nonexistant_path`
`try ls -la ~`
`try echo unreachable`
then it doesn't work: first `try` should stop the execution, because `ls nonexistant_path` fails. But it doesn't stop, and unreachable code executes. the error message produced by `ls nonexistant_path` is buried beneath long outputs of other commands. It's sad, because unlike the other answers, your answer prints the failed command, and that's important. If it worked correctly for all kinds of commands, I'd mark it as the best answer, despite the low number of upvotes. Can you fix it?

Comment: @Arqwer: I think it should be `try ls -la ~ && try ls nonexistant_path`

Comment: Ah, that means that user should modify commands and can't just copy-paste them.

Answer (score 3):

Use this solution if you want to do it in interactive shell:

```bsh
set -x; command_1 && command_2 && command_3 && echo "Everything OK" || echo "Error while executing last command"; set +x
```

Output when all commands succeed:

```
+ command_1
output of command 1
+ command_2
output of command 2
+ command_3
output of command 3
+ echo "Everything OK"
Everything OK
+ set +x
```

Output when the `command_2` fails:

```
+ command_1
output of command 1
+ command_2
output of command 2
+ echo "Error while executing last command"
+ set +x
```

---

The `set -x` command enables logging of all executed commands. Logged commands are prefixed with one or more pluses (style can be changed using variable `$PS4`). `set +x` disables this mode.

You should put the `set -x` and `set +x` to the same line because `set -x` enables logging of *all* executed commands — including `$COMMAND_PROMPT` and commands executed by it.

---

You can also use it for shell scripts:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash -ex

command_1
command_2
command_3
```

Shell options can be embedded in the shebang line. `-e` makes shell exit after first failed command (like when all lines end with `&&`). `-x` enables logging of commands. Note that you can pass only *one* argument to the interpreter. Use `/usr/bin/env` to pass multiple arguments (`#!/usr/bin/env -S bash -ex arg1 arg2 argN`).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps just a function for what you are already doing:

```
function run_cmd
    ( $* && echo OK $* || ( echo FAILED $*; false ) )

run_cmd echo 1 &&
run_cmd false 2 &&
run_cmd echo 3 &&
echo DONE || echo FAILED
```

Output of this is:

```
1
OK echo 1
FAILED false 2
FAILED
```